Correct place of adjectival clause

A few stars are known which are hardly bigger than the earth, but most of them are so large that hundreds of thousands of Earth's can be packed inside each and leave room to spare.

Usually, an adjectival clause comes after the noun it describes, but here it is taking place after the verb (known) instead of the noun (stars). Secondly, the verb 'leave' is working either as a main verb or as a bare infinitive.

The relative clause "which are hardly bigger than the earth" is said to be postposed, because it occurs in postposed position, at the end of the clause containing its antecedent. It's better to call "leave" the 'predicator', or simply 'head' of the relative clause, rather than the ill-named 'main verb'

I would repeat "stars" instead of saying "most of them" :  "but most stars are so large..."

Do this: A few stars, hardly bigger than the earth, are known

Yes, that's correct.  Normally the relative clause follows the verb, but here (and following the "end weight" principle) it is moved to the end of the clause.  The alternative

A few stars {which are hardly bigger than the Earth} are known.

suffers from the problem of having a long and complex subject that delays the verb. The author's solution to this is to place the relative clause at the end.  It is correct grammar.
The word "leave" is bare infinitive.  Compare "I can eat ice cream and be happy".  It means "I can be happy by eating ice cream". Or in the Earth example, You could leave space even after packing hundreds of thousands of Earths into a star.

Who would write that? A few stars,  hardly bigger than the earth, are known etc.

You could also write:

A few stars hardly bigger than the earth are known, but most stars are so large that ....

